# Postgresql database backup within tables

Tags: postgresql, database-backups

Is there any way to create a backup of particular row within a table in postgresql?

Answer (score 0):

```
COPY (SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id = 42)
TO STDOUT (FORMAT 'csv');
```

Comment: I am using ubuntu server 12.04 where to apply this command? Can you please give me full guidance?

Comment: Using the database client of your choice. If you  [edit] the question and describe what exactly you want with more detail, my answer could be more specific.

Comment: I have one table in source database named "db" In their there is a one table named "test" There is a 100 raws is there I want only 50 raws. This 50 raws must be inserted in target database named "db" And table name  "test" Then how to restore?

Comment: `COPY ... TO 'file'` to write the desired rows out, then load them with `COPY ... FROM 'file'` into the other database. Read the documentation on `COPY` for details.

Comment: Can you provide me documentation link?

Comment: Yes, of course, [here you are](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html). `COPY` as such writes files on the database server. To copy data to the client, you can use `psql`'s `\copy`.

Comment: Can you please provide me your whatsApp number?

Comment: I don't have a WhatsApp number. You can contact my company for professional consulting.

Answer (score 0):

You can also just backup data to another table with:

```
create table backup as select * from mytable where id=24;
```